# Existence and uniqueness of ODE in implicit form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

there are a lot of well known theorems about existence and uniqueness of solutions to ODE's like for instance the Peano existence theorem or the Picard-Lindelöf theorem. I am wondering why those theorems only make statements about equations which can be written like this:
$$y'=f(t,y).$$

But they do not deal with more general equations like
$$f(t,y,y')=0.$$

Are there existence and uniqueness statements for the more general second kind of equation above? I suppose they are more difficult to dealt with. Why is this the case?

Best wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the theorem can fail if we cannot express $y'$ as a function of $t$ and $y$.

*Existence Fails:* $(y')^2+1=0$. If so, then $(y')^2 = -1$ but $(y')^2 \geq 0$ so no such $y'$ exists (over the real numbers). Thus the equation has no solution.

*Uniqueness Fails:* $2y (y') -4t^3=0$ with $y(0)=0$. This implies $2y(y')=4t^3$ so (using separation of variables): $y^2 = t^4+C$ and so $y= \pm \sqrt{t^4+C}$. If $y(0)=0$ we have $\pm \sqrt{0^4+C}=0$ so $C=0$. Notice that **both** $y=-\sqrt{t^4}=-t^2$ *and* $y=\sqrt{t^4}=t^2$ are solutions -- uniqueness fails!

Answer (score 2):

If the equation is locally solvable for $y'$, then again the local version of Picard-Lindelöf applies, as any continuously differentiable function is locally Lipschitz.

If the equation is not solvable, then you are in the land of DAE - differential-algebraic equations, where solvability is a much more complicated beast.